# What is wrong with my "if" statement in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I am completely new to bash(ing) and I would like to understand what I am doing wrong with this script. I am able to open the script and type a number but it closes the terminal without any response. I would also like to thank you ahead of time for taking the time to look this over. I greatly appreciate it.

```
#!/bin/bash

#options 1-4 have options, option 5-x is else command
echo "Type one of the following:"
echo "1 - whoami"
echo "2 - df"
echo "3 - date"
echo "4 - cal"
echo -n "select option:"

read option

if [ "$option" == "1" ]
    then #use whoami command
        echo "whoami"

elif [ "$option" == "2" ]
    then #use df command
        echo "df"
elif [ "$option" == "3" ]
    then #use date command
        echo "date"
elif [ "$option" == "4" ]
    then #use cal command
        echo "cal"

else #red colored error message
    echo "You make an invalid selection. Exiting."
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: How are executing the script?

Comment: Works for me in bash. Doesn't work with `/bin/sh` though, since `==` is not POSIX compatible (use `=` instead).

Comment: I am right clicking the file and opening it and "running it in terminal"

Comment: It exits immediately after outputting the choice you made; at that point your terminal emulator is closing the window because it's configured to do so after its initial command exits.

Comment: I actually think I figured it out... I feel silly now. Thank you all! I did not realize that ./ should have been used before the actual file.

Comment: My 2 cents: Best way to debug a bash script is to execute it in a terminal emulator. Adding to @chepner reply, if you execute it in a terminal, you will be able to see the output text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in you exit 0. Because the exit 0 will executes it will exit the program. If you enter any choice it will print the output for that choice and exit. If you want to do the operations continuously you can use the loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use "-eq" operator for comparision instead of "=="

```
*if [ "$option" -eq "1" ]*
```

Comment: In this case there's no guarantee the user entered a number, so I'd say string comparison is more appropriate. (Although `==` is a bashism, so `=` is actually better.)

Answer (score 0):

In bash for comparison you can't use '==' just use '=' instead.

```
 if [ "$option" = "1" ]
```

Comment: Actually `==` is supported in bash. Just that it is not POSIX compatible